# How to access a member of const enum indirectly through a variable?

Tags: go, constants

I have a const enum like

```
const(
PROD_BASEURL="http://prod.abc.com"
TEST_BASEURL="http://test.abc.com"
)
```

In one of my functions, I am taking environment as input and want to access the const members accordingly.

```
envUrl := env + "_BASEURL"
```

Here env is the input which can be PROD or TEST.
Now, how can I access the const members through `envUrl` variable without directly specifying 
`PROD_BASEURL`?

Comment: You can't do that in Go, it is simply not possible to reference an identifier by using strings. That means that you have to options, either use the identifier as you've declared it, or don't use it at all, use something else instead. Probably the most simple solution to what you need is to do a conditional, `if` or `switch` on the `env` value and then set the `envUrl` by referencing the full identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems that your use-case asks for a [map](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action). With a map you can write your code like this:

```golang
baseurls := map[string]string{
    "PROD": "http://prod.abc.com",
    "TEST": "http://test.abc.com",
}

envUrl := baseurls[env]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by using structs, instead of constants:

```
type EnvSet struct {
   BaseURL string
   // other env specific setting
}

var Prod =EnvSet{BaseURL:"...",...}
var Dev = EnvSet{BaseURL:"...",...}

var selectedEnv EnvSet
switch env {
  case "prod": selectedEnv=Prod
  case "dev": selectedEnv=Dev
}
```